# Render the datatable's row based on the var

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using primeface in a project and I have this dataTable

```
<p:dataTable 
            id="list"
            var="agendamento" 
            value="#{agendamentoListagemManagedBean.agendamentoDataModel}"
            rowKey="#{agendamento.id}"
            selection="#{solicitacaoManagedBean.agendamentosSelecionados}"
            lazy="true">

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" 
            style="width:20px;text-align:center"
            rendered="#{ !agendamentoManagedBean.isAgendamentoLivreParaCopiar(agendamento)}"/>

        <p:column width="70" headerText="#">
            <h:outputText value="#{agendamento.id}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

So, i want to conditionally render the checkbox of each row based on the "agendamento"

Comment: Is the dataTable showing all records from 'agendamentoDataModel'? Are the selection checkboxes visible or not? Is the method 'isAgendamentoLivreParaCopiar' being called for every object in 'agendamentoDataModel'?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to conditionally render the checkbox of the `<p:column selectionMode="multiple">`, or do you want to "conditionally render" the entire row? (i.e. having the same effect as the item isn't present inside `agendamentoDataModel`) The former is not trivial, while the latter is easy (just provide exactly the model the view expects).